# Выполнить код каждый определённый промежуток времени

Tags: python, telebot, schedule

мне захотелось сделать так, чтобы бот каждый час, либо в определённое время отправлял какое-нибудь сообщение в чат.
Функцию внутри бота написал, которая проверяет, наступило ли подходящее время - модуль ***schedule***, но выполнения этой функции дождаться не получается

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('***')

try:
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
    def check(message):
        if not check_permission(message.from_user.username):
            bot.reply_to(message, text=f'Bot status: working, {message.from_user.username}!')

    def GoCode():
        variants = ['Время ботать?!', 'Ботать ботать боооотаааать!!', 'Я сделал алгосы, а ТЫ?', 'Щас бы тяночку...']
        var = random.randint(0, 4)
        bot.send_message(-1001803296788, text=f'{variants[var]}')


    schedule.every(1).hour.do(GoCode)
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

except:
    print('crashed')
```

К сожалению, это не работает - почему?

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , вот так лучше?

Comment: документация? ```while True: schedule.run_pending(); time.sleep(1);``` ?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков да, но из-за этого while не выполняется код, расположенный ниже - бот не реагирует на сообщения

Comment: schedule.every(1).hour.do(GoCode) GoCode точно должен быть не вызываемым в данном месте?

Comment: Тогда вам нужна [асинхронная](https://python-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/examples/asyncio.html) обработка :)